# Problem in basic example of Callbacks in Javascript

Tags: javascript, callback

The HTML file has a empty body.

This is the first code without editing anything

```
const posts = [
    { title: 'Post One', body: 'This is post one'},
    { title: 'Post two', body: 'This is post two'}
];

function getPosts(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
        let output = '';
        posts.forEach((post,index) => {
            output += `<li>${post.title}</li>`;
        });
        document.body.innerHTML = output;
    },1000);
}

function createPost(post){
    setTimeout(()=>{
        posts.push(post);
    }, 2000);
}

getPosts()

createPosts({title:'Post three', body:'This is post three'});
```

The output we get is

```
Post One
Post two
```

We are not seeing 'Post Three' as expected.

Now we will pass `getPosts` function as an argument to the `createPost` function

```
const posts = [
    { title: 'Post One', body: 'This is post one'},
    { title: 'Post two', body: 'This is post two'}
];

function getPosts(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
        let output = '';
        posts.forEach((post,index) => {
            output += `<li>${post.title}</li>`;
        });
        document.body.innerHTML = output;
    },1000);
}

function createPost(post,callback){
    setTimeout(()=>{
        posts.push(post);
        callback();
    }, 2000);
}

createPosts({title:'Post three', body:'This is post three'},getPosts);
```

Now the output is completely blank. Even `Post One` and `Post Two` is not added to DOM let alone `Post Three` which we expected in this case

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: hint: use the browsers **developer** tools console to debug your code

Comment: @JaromandaX Sure, Henceforth I will make it a point to wander around there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining the method `createPost` but calling `createPosts`.

```js
const posts = [{
    title: 'Post One',
    body: 'This is post one'
  },
  {
    title: 'Post two',
    body: 'This is post two'
  }
];

function getPosts() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    let output = '';
    posts.forEach((post, index) => {
      output += `<li>${post.title}</li>`;
    });
    document.body.innerHTML = output;
  }, 1000);
}

function createPost(post, callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    posts.push(post);
    callback();
  }, 2000);
}

createPost({
  title: 'Post three',
  body: 'This is post three'
}, getPosts);
```

Comment: That was a dumb mistake. Thanks. By the way which extension or IDE did you use which formatted the code like this?

Answer (score 1):

When I was writing an answer, saw that someone replied already.

Just wanted to mention that while in the 2nd case you should get what you want, typo is a devil, the first case is clearly a wrong way of doing what you wanted.

`setTimeout` with a second evidently will work out faster that the same `setTimeout` with 2 seconds.

Comment: I was just revisiting callbacks, promises, async, await by trying basic examples from some tutorials after not touching JS for quite some while and this happened. Anyway, Thanks!